# Select specified month date from numpy array (datetime object)

Tags: python, datetime, numpy

I have an array like below, and I want to select the date with month ==1 and month ==2 and month== 3, how should I do this?

```
a = np.array([datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 10, 11, 55),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 20, 11, 55),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 2, 6, 11, 55),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 2, 16, 11, 55),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 3, 2, 11, 55),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 3, 12, 11, 55),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 3, 22, 11, 55),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 4, 8, 11, 55),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 4, 18, 11, 55),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 5, 4, 11, 55),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 5, 14, 11, 55)]
```

Comment: Are you restricted to using numpy arrays? If you placed the data in a pandas df then this would be easy

Comment: how to use pandas? @EdChum

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/ and also [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.0/10min.html)

Comment: This array is `dtype=object`.  Each element is a pointer to a `datetime` object.  It is basically the same as a list of those objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a` is an array of objects (`dtype=object`).  It stores pointers to datetime objects, much like lists.  Most math and logical operations don't work with this kind of array.  That is why `Wouter's` answer uses list comprehensions.

There is a `np.datetime64` dtype that implements a number of numeric operations.  Mostly I see it in the context of structured arrays produced from `csv` files (via `genfromtxt`).

`a` could be converted to this type with another comprehension:

```
In [202]: b=np.array([np.datetime64(x.isoformat(),'s') for x in a])
In [203]: b
Out[203]: 
array(['2015-01-01T10:11:55-0800', '2015-01-01T20:11:55-0800',
       '2015-02-02T06:11:55-0800', '2015-03-02T16:11:55-0800',
       '2015-02-03T02:11:55-0800', '2015-01-03T12:11:55-0800',
       '2015-04-03T22:11:55-0700', '2015-03-04T08:11:55-0800',
       '2015-05-04T18:11:55-0700', '2015-01-05T04:11:55-0800',
       '2015-03-05T14:11:55-0800'], dtype='datetime64[s]')
```

I don't see a way of pulling out the 'month' itself, but it can be cast (viewed) to a month `dtype`:

```
In [136]: b1=b.astype('datetime64[M]')

In [137]: b1
Out[137]: 
array(['2015-01', '2015-01', '2015-02', '2015-03', '2015-02', '2015-01',
       '2015-04', '2015-03', '2015-05', '2015-01', '2015-03'], dtype='datetime64[M]')
```

and a mask generated with

```
In [138]: b1==np.datetime64('2015-01')
Out[138]: 
array([ True,  True, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False,
        True, False], dtype=bool)
```

and the 3 month groups selected via:

```
In [141]: a[b1==np.datetime64('2015-01')]
Out[141]: 
array([datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 10, 11, 55),
       datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 20, 11, 55),
       datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 3, 12, 11, 55),
       datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 5, 4, 11, 55)], dtype=object)

In [142]: a[b1==np.datetime64('2015-02')]
Out[142]: 
array([datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 2, 6, 11, 55),
       datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 3, 2, 11, 55)], dtype=object)

In [143]: a[b1==np.datetime64('2015-03')]
Out[143]: 
array([datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 2, 16, 11, 55),
       datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 4, 8, 11, 55),
       datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 5, 14, 11, 55)], dtype=object)
```

I haven't done much with this `dtype`.  In this case I don't see much advantage over treating `a` as a plain list, but if you are doing time and date differences, the numeric datatime is worth considering.

Answer (score 1):

Just select everything with month < 4:

```
result1 = [d for d in a if d.month == 1 ]
result2 = [d for d in a if d.month == 2 ]
result3 = [d for d in a if d.month == 3 ]
```

returns:

```
result1 =
[datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 10, 11, 55), 
 datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 20, 11, 55), 
 datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 3, 12,11, 55), 
 datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 5, 4, 11, 55),

result2 =  
 [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 2, 6, 11, 55), 
 datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 3, 2, 11, 55)]

result3 = 
 [datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 2, 16, 11, 55), 
 datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 4, 8, 11, 55), 
 datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 5, 14, 11, 55)]
```

for your example.

Comment: thanks, but what I need is to select date respective, i.e, frist select month=1 and give it to a new array, then reselect another condition and give the result to another array~

Comment: @Owen I edited the answer, is this what you mean? if you want to give another condition, just repeat the same pattern, e.g. `result1_1 = [d for d in result1 if d.day==1]` will return the dates from result1 where the day ==1